# Problem with diacritics on psql 9.0 (PostgreSQL)

Tags: postgresql, utf-8, psql

I have two instances of PostgreSQL installed on my server: 8.3 and 9.0. There seams to be some problem with Polish diacritic characters (like ółęąśżźć) on postgresql 9.0 client - psql.

When I connect to DB (either 8.3 or 9.0) with psql 8.3 - I can type all diacritics on the terminal without any problems:

```
www:/tmp# sudo -u postgres /usr/lib/postgresql/8.3/bin/psql -q
postgres=# ółśćń
```

However, when I connect to the same DBs with psql 9.0 client - I can't type diacritics on the terminal anymore:

```
www:/tmp# sudo -u postgres /usr/lib/postgresql/8.3/bin/psql -q
```

Here are some encoding settings:

```
www:/tmp# sudo -u postgres /usr/lib/postgresql/9.0/bin/psql -q -c "show client_encoding"
 client_encoding
-----------------
 UTF8
(1 row)
```

.

```
www:/tmp# sudo -u postgres /usr/lib/postgresql/8.3/bin/psql -q -c "show client_encoding"
 client_encoding
-----------------
 UTF8
(1 row)
```

.

```
www:/tmp# sudo -u postgres /usr/lib/postgresql/9.0/bin/psql -q -l
                                         List of databases
        Name         |    Owner     | Encoding |  Collation  |    Ctype    |   Access privileges
---------------------+--------------+----------+-------------+-------------+-----------------------
 postgres            | postgres     | UTF8     | pl_PL.UTF-8 | pl_PL.UTF-8 |
```

.

```
www:/tmp# echo $LANG
pl_PL.UTF-8
```

It looks like DB/cluster configuration doesn't matter - if psql 8.x on terminal works fine and psql 9.x does not. Any idea how to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably related to psql 9.0.2 switching from readline to libedit. You could try (works for me, Ubuntu 10.04):

```
rlwrap psql -n ...
```

Alternatively:

```
LD_PRELOAD='/lib/libreadline.so.5' psql ...
```

Or, it is suggested to install termcap, but I haven't tried this (no apparent way to do this in Ubuntu).